# Disable page that shows correlation ID?

Tags: 2013, 2016

I have a sharepoint farm on a customer, and they are strict with security.
They scanned the entire website with some tool and now they say that the scanner when trying URLS, sometimes it gets the page where it shows the correlation ID.

Is that possible to dissable? or a workaround for that "vulnerability".

thanks

Comment: SharePoint will show the correlation ID on (almost?) every error page. There are 1715143 things a user can do to get an error page in SharePoint. Ask them if they pee with their eyes closed as well.

Comment: but can it be disabled or not? I need official documentation to show them. :)

Comment: Sure, can be disabled. Only one way though... turn off SharePoint

Comment: I will send them a link to this post, lol!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a vulnerability. It's something their scanner is doing that is tripping an error. I'd tell them to ignore it.